# Printing a zoomed area with DjVu - problems

Tags: windows-7, printing, djvu

I'm trying to print images from the Swedish National Archives which uses DjVu as their viewing/printing software.  I can print the entire page with not issues.  However, when I zoom into a specific area to see it enlarged and try to print the zoomed area it prints the very center of the page at that zoomed level.  No matter what area of the page I'm zoomed into (top-left, right, etc.) it prints the center of the page.  It's like the software doesn't know that I'm trying to print a specific area.

When I do a print preview it also shows the center of the page zoomed.

I have a PC with Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1, IE v11.0, and an HP Deskjet 6940 printer, if that helps.

Appreciate any help you may be able to provide.